# Write values from workbook to one stored on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am attempting to take data from specific cells in a workbook, and then save to a new row in a workbook on our corporate SharePoint.

I think my primary issue is "finding" the SharePoint document. I have a sample path in my code below.

I pulled code off of a website for sharing from workbook to workbook and that is the heavily commented section of my code and the area I believe may have the issue.

```vb
Sub depositSummaryUpdater()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"

Dim managerName As String
managerName = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 4).Value

Dim depositActual As Currency
depositActual = ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 9).Value

Dim depositRevel As Currency
depositRevel = ActiveSheet.Cells(18, 3).Value

Dim depositVariance As Currency
depositVariance = ActiveSheet.Cells(15, 3).Value

Dim hundredCountDeposit As Currency
hundredCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 7).Value

Dim fiftyCountDeposit As Currency
fiftyCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 7).Value

Dim twentyCountDeposit As Currency
twentyCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 7).Value

Dim tenCountDeposit As Currency
tenCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 7).Value

Dim fiveCountDeposit As Currency
fiveCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 7).Value

Dim twoCountDeposit As Currency
twoCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 7).Value

Dim oneCountDeposit As Currency
oneCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 7).Value

Dim quarterCountDeposit As Currency
quarterCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 10).Value

Dim dimeCountDeposit As Currency
dimeCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, 10).Value

Dim nickelCountDeposit As Currency
nickelCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 10).Value

Dim pennyCountDeposit As Currency
pennyCountDeposit = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 10).Value

Dim tillDate As Date
tillDate = Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4), "YY-MM-DD")

Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim destLastRow As Integer

'Dim depositPathString As String
'depostPathString = "https://ourcorporatesharpointaddress.sharepoint.com/sites/tills/Shared%20Documents/Safe%20Deposit/Safe_Deposit_Summary"

'Set variables for destination sheet
'Set wsDest = Workbooks(depositPathString).Worksheets("Deposit Summary")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("https://ourcorporatesharepointaddress.sharepoint.com/sites/tills/Shared%20Documents/Safe%20Deposit/Safe_Deposit_Summary").Worksheets("Deposit Summary")

'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
'Offset property moves down 1 row
destLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

'3. Copy & Paste Data
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 1) = tillDate
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 2) = hundredCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 3) = fiftyCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 4) = twentyCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 5) = tenCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 6) = fiveCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 7) = twoCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 8) = oneCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 9) = quarterCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 10) = dimeCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 11) = nickelCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 12) = pennyCountDeposit
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 13) = depositActual
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 14) = depositRevel
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 15) = depositVariance
Set wsDest.Cells(destLastRow, 16) = managerName

ActiveSheet.Protect "password", True, True

End Sub
```

Comment: you don't have an extension on your `wsdest` workbook.  You need to choose an actual workbook.

Comment: Are you opening the destination workbook from SharePoint? At some point you need to call `workbooks.Open()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
'Note needs the workbook name included, not just the path
Const DEST_WB_PATH As String = "https://tangandbiscuitcom.sharepoint.com/sites/tills/" & _
                            "Shared%20Documents/Safe%20Deposit/Safe_Deposit_Summary/Data.xlsx"
Dim wbDest As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet

Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(DEST_WB_PATH)
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Deposit Summary")

With wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
    .Cells(1).Value = tillDate
    .Cells(2).Value = hundredCountDeposit
    '... etc etc
End With
```

Comment: Tim, You are the man! I am sure I can just find this answer on SO but I will also ask here. now that this is working, after running the macro, it leaves the destination sheet I called still open. what additional code would I need to simply close this? would I just do something like ``` Workbooks.Close(Dest_WB_PATH) ```

Comment: `wbDest.Close True` to save changes

Answer (score 0):

If you have need to make your edits invisibly (without the target file opening and closing), you can use the application object (the default value for Application.Visible is false).  Also I'm using a named range in the external file to target the cell I want to edit.

```
Dim oApp As New Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Workbook
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim oRange As Range

Set oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Open("my_sharepoint_file_url")
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("my_sheet_name")
Set oRange = oSheet.Range("my_range_name")
oRange.Value = "foo"

oBook.Close True
oApp.Quit
```